# Understanding Transitive Constituents $G^{\Delta}$ : Image of the Action of $G$ on $\Delta$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, definition

I am trying to understand the following definition found in an [article (link given)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08266.pdf):

${\rm Sym}(\Omega)$ -the symmetric group on the set $\Omega$.

If $G < {\rm Sym}(\Omega)$, and $\Delta$ is a subset of $\Omega$ fixed by $G$,

then the image of the action of $G$ on $\Delta$

is called the permutation group induced on $\Delta$  by $G$, and written $G^{\Delta}$.

I am not clear about the "the image of the action of $G$ on $\Delta$", does it mean we will consider all elements of $G$ as $G^{\Delta}$?

Or do we consider only those group elements of $G$ that moves domain elements of $\Delta$ as $G^{\Delta}$?

Please show with examples.

Also, $G_x$ and $G_x^\Delta$ acting on different sets suborbit $\Omega\setminus\{x\}$ and $\Delta$ respectively, is $\Omega\setminus\{x\} \neq \Delta$ always?

Note:

Can any one name a book that contains the above definition with example? I have checked Dixon's book, it's not there.

Comment: Since $gx\in\Delta$ for every $g\in G$ and every $x\in \Delta$, the restriction of the action of $g$ to delta is an element of $\mathrm{Sym}(\Delta)$. The map that sends $g$ to $g|_{\Delta}\in\mathrm{Sym}(\Delta)$  makes $G$ into a permutation group on $\Delta$. That's the "image of the action on $\Delta$".

Comment: $\Delta = \Omega \setminus \{x\}$ is possible, but that would imply that $x$ is a fixed point of $G$ i.e. $G = G_x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a permutation group on a set $\Omega$, with orbits $\Omega_i, i \in I$. Then $G$ induces a transitive permutation group $G^\Omega_i$ on $\Omega_i$; these are called the  **TRANSITIVE CONSTITUENTS** of $G$.

In some sense, $G$ is built from its **transitive constituents**; indeed,

$G$ is a subdirect product of the $G^\Omega_i$ (that is, the corresponding
projection maps $G \rightarrow G^\Omega_i$ are surjective).

For example, if $G = \{1,(1,2)(3,4)\}$ and $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$

then the orbits are $\Omega_1  = \{1, 2\}, \Omega_2= \{3, 4\}$,

and $G$ is a proper subdirect product of the **transitive constituents** $G^\Omega_1 = \{1, (1,2)\}, G^\Omega_2 = \{1,(3,4)\}$.

-Topics in Permutation Group Theory (page 7), Lectures by Tim Burness (University of Bristol, UK), Young Algebraists’ Conference (Lausanne, June 2014).

Also from Permutation Groups by Peter J. Cameronon, on page 4, we find similar explanation:

> Consider the two permutation groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ given by
> $$G_1 = \{(1),(1 2)(3 4)\},$$
> $$G_2 = \{(1),(1 2),(3 4),(12) (3 4)\}.$$
> Each has two orbits, namely $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{3, 4\}$;
>
> in each case, both the transitive constituents are cyclic groups of order $2$.
>
> We see that $G_2$ is the full cartesian product of these two cyclic groups,
>
> whereas $G_1$ is a proper subcartesian product.

Definition:

Let $(G_i), i\in I$ be a family of groups. A subgroup $H$ of the direct product $\Pi_{i\in I}G_i$ is said to be a [subdirect product (or subcartesian product)](https://planetmath.org/subdirectproductofgroups) of $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ if $\pi_i(H)=G_i$ for each $i\in I$, where $\pi_i:\Pi_{i\in I}G_i\rightarrow G_i$ is the $i$-th projection map.